# ASP.NET code behind file not nested under the related aspx file in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In my C# ASP.NET Web Site using .NET Framework 4.0, I have a couple of pages where the related .cs file is not under its related aspx file.  I recently moved the files to a subdirectory.  I have 10 pages and for 8 of them the move worked just fine and the .cs file is under the aspx.  However for two pages, the .cs file now no longer shows below the aspx file.  How can I fix this so that the cs is shown correctly underneath the aspx file?  When I compare the top of the markup pages, the two problem pages look just like the other 8 pages.  I don't see any issues there.

Comment: Try to exclude / include them ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to fix this.  First I tried excluding and including the files in the Solution Explorer but that resulted in the same results.  The way to fix this is to move the files out of the project, then refresh the Solution Explorer.  At this point, the files will no longer be part of the project.  Then move the files back into the project.  Then refresh and the .cs files should be shown below their associated aspx files.

Answer (score 8):

First make sure they have the same name (except for the extension of course). If this does not help and it's a Web Application then try removing the 3 files (.aspx, .aspx.cs, aspx.designer.cs) from the project by right-click -> 'exclude from project'. Then add them again. The easiest way is to show all files (hint: screenshot), then right-click -> 'Include in project'.

[image: VS 2010 Solution Explorer]

Comment: It is a Web Site instead of a Web Application.  I tried excluding the aspx and cs files and then including them again but had the same results.

Answer (score 1):

In general for VS projects the nesting is driven by the `<DependentUpon/>` element. You can fix it by editing the project file directly.
Change:

```
    <Compile Include="blah.child" />
```

To:

```
    <Compile Include="blah.child">
      <DependentUpon>blah.parent</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```

This works for any nested files, like `.sass -> .css -> .min.css`

```
    <Compile Include="blah.css">
      <DependentUpon>blah.scss</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="blah.min.css">
      <DependentUpon>blah.css</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```